# Apache Spark: Optimization Filter

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce

So this is more of a design question.

Right now, I have a list of patient ids and I need to put them into one of 3 buckets.

The bucket they go into is completely based on the following RDDs

```
case class Diagnostic(patientID:String, date: Date, code: String)
case class LabResult(patientID: String, date: Date, testName: String, value: Double)
case class Medication(patientID: String, date: Date, medicine: String)
```

Right now I'm basically going to each RDD 3-4 times per patient_id per bucket to see if it goes into a bucket. This runs extremely slow, is there anything I can do to improve this?

Example is for bucket 1, I have to check if there a diagnostic, for patient_id 1 (even though there are multiple), has a code of 1 and that patient_id 1 has a medication where medicine is foo

Right now I'm doing this as two filters (one on each RDD)....

Ugly code example

```
if (labResult.filter({ lab =>
        val testName = lab.testName

        testName.contains("glucose")
      }).count == 0) {
      return false
    } else if (labResult.filter({ lab =>
      val testName = lab.testName
      val testValue = lab.value

      // all the built in rules
      (testName == "hba1c" && testValue >= 6.0) ||
      (testName == "hemoglobin a1c" && testValue >= 6.0) ||
      (testName == "fasting glucose" && testValue >= 110) ||
      (testName == "fasting blood glucose" && testValue >= 110) ||
      (testName == "glucose" && testValue >= 110) ||
      (testName == "glucose, serum" && testValue >= 110)
    }).count > 0) {
      return false
    } else if (diagnostic.filter({ diagnosis =>
      val code = diagnosis.code

      (code == "790.21")  ||
      (code == "790.22")  ||
      (code == "790.2")   ||
      (code == "790.29")  ||
      (code == "648.81")  ||
      (code == "648.82")  ||
      (code == "648.83")  ||
      (code == "648.84")  ||
      (code == "648.0")   ||
      (code == "648.01")  ||
      (code == "648.02")  ||
      (code == "648.03")  ||
      (code == "648.04")  ||
      (code == "791.5")   ||
      (code == "277.7")   ||
      (code == "v77.1")   ||
      (code == "256.4")   ||
      (code == "250.*")
    }).count > 0) {
      return false
    }

    true
```

Comment: can you please post the code. it will easy to understand and also will help in suggesting improvements.

Comment: Posted the ugliest part (the filter)

Comment: You are trying to implement a decision tree ?

Comment: Esentially yes, like I mentioned, I need to put a patient_id into one of three buckets, but I need to look all of  their RDD info to determine which bucket to put them in

Comment: I'm not sure quite so far what does the first condition represent. if (labResult....) true),

Comment: The first checks if they have a lab with glucose at all (if not, they are not part of this bucket), second checks if any of their labs is incorrect (if not, not part of bucket) finally, we check the code to see if it's any invalid code, if not, then not part of the bucket, pass all checks, part of bucket

Comment: ok give me a moment to look at all that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104240/discussion-between-eliasah-and-amchang87).